# d3js filtering out the old data

Tags: d3.js

I'm working on d3js and i'm not sure how to update the data.
I'm trying to show only 10 circles and whenever the data gets more than 10, it pushes out the oldest one and draw the new circle.

I tried dataset.splice(0,1) then push the data in, but the graph isn't responding. My guess is that you're not supposed to do that, insted use filter method on d3js, but I don't know how to make it work.

[here's the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shioihi/vm6mg5kg/3/)

```js
w = 800;
h = 300;
var svg = d3.select("#target").append("svg").attr({
  class: "space-screen",
  height: h,
  width: w
});

var dataSet = new Array();
var counter = 0;

function addData() {
  dataObj = {
    date: new Date(),
    count: counter
  };
  counter++;

  if (dataSet.length >= 10) {
    dataSet.splice(0,1);
  }
  dataSet.push(dataObj);
  var circle = svg.selectAll("circle").data(dataSet);
  circle.exit().remove();
  circle.enter().append("circle").attr({
    cx: function(d, i) {
      return i * 50 + 50
    },
    cy: h / 2,
    r: function(d) {
      return d.count * 5;
    },
    fill: "blue"
  });
}
setInterval(addData, 500);
```

```css
.space-screen {
  background-color: #fefefe;
}
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <p>D3 test</p>
  <div id="target"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you using selection exit().remove() you should define a key to mark a data as unique.

so instead of this;

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle").data(dataSet);
```

it should be

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle").data(dataSet, function(d){ return d.date.getTime();});
```

working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/htuecg2f/)

Comment: This solves it! thank you so much! are there any sources that describes this? I never knew you can define a key to mark data as unique.

Comment: here it is https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data read the key section.

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't know there was a system like that. Thank you!